# Make Gatsby refuse to compile on TypeScript error

Tags: typescript, gatsby, tsconfig

In my CRA TypeScript projects, when I have a TS error in my code, TS prevents the dev server from compiling and instead displays the error in browser and console. I like this behaviour.

In my new Gatsby project, this doesn't happen. IDE tells me about the error, but `gatsby develop` runs the code regardless, just like it would with plain js. How can I configure it to behave like what I'm used to from CRA?

I use `gatsby-plugin-typescript`.
This is my gatsby-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/assets`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        start_url: `/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-typescript`,
      options: {
        isTSX: true, // defaults to false
        allExtensions: true, // defaults to false
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-emotion`,
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
}
```

this is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, to my knowledge, this can't be achieved with `gatsby-plugin-typescript`.

According to the [Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-typescript/):

> This plugin uses babel-plugin-transform-typescript to transpile TypeScript. It does not do type checking.

If you want to achieve the same behaviour as in CRA, you can use [gatsby-plugin-ts](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-ts/) instead. Be advised that, unlike `gatsby-plugin-typescript`, it is "unofficial". I came across it by trawling through Gatsby starters until I found [this one](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/starters/Tielem/gatsby-typescript-eslint-prettier-starter), which is excellent.